# How to send CSV into file in straming mode where i get input in "java.io.PipedInputStream@1bca8e6" format in mule esb?

Tags: file, csv, streaming, mule

My requirement is, I get input xml and based on some condition checking(using choice) I need to send into 2 different files. As I'm getting big file(100-400MB) I'm sending in stream mode(by enable streaming in file and datamapper components).

It is working fine for small size input xml(10-20MB). But when I give large input xml. Condition checking and XML to CSV conversion is working fine but while writing CSVB-data I'm getting error message.,

INFO  2015-09-08 12:03:49,227 [[simplebatch_1].simplebatchFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: default logger java.io.PipedInputStream@1bca8e6

INFO  2015-09-08 12:03:49,258 [[simplebatch_1].File1.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'File1.dispatcher.29118412'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-09-08 12:03:49,258 [[simplebatch_1].File1.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'File1.dispatcher.29118412'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-09-08 12:03:49,258 [[simplebatch_1].File1.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: D:\MulePOC's\output\myoutput1
ERROR 2015-09-08 12:03:54,999 [XML_READER0_0] org.jetel.graph.Node: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 2015-09-08 12:03:55,000 [WatchDog_0] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Component [XML READER:XML_READER0] finished with status ERROR.
 Java heap space

Please suggest me on this., Thanks..,

Answer (score 0):

You need increase your JVM memory for Mule. You can found the config file in `$MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf`

You will found something like this:

```
# Increase Permanent Generation Size from default of 64m
# Increase this value if you get "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error"
# This property is not used when running java 8 and may cause a warning.
wrapper.java.additional.7=-XX:PermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.8=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

# GC settings
wrapper.java.additional.9=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.10=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
wrapper.java.additional.11=-XX:+UseParNewGC
wrapper.java.additional.12=-XX:NewSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.13=-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.14=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8
```

You can change this configurations as you like.